# routing home page as the #new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want `static_pages/home` to be configured as `lists#new` so that at the request for the home page, the browser will render `home.html.erb` with the user input form upon the submitting of which a new `list` entry is created in the db. I tried adding this to the `routes.rb`

```
resources :lists
root 'static_pages#home'
match '/static_pages/home', to: 'lists#new', via: 'get'
```

but this way the app disregards the home view completely and only loads the `_form.html.erb` partial.

And the second question after this, should this form that will be displayed on the home page go into the `_form.html.erb` partial?

Comment: delete the file `/public/index.html` and update `root :to => 'lists#new'` in /config/routes.rb file   and I am not able to understand your second question

Comment: This makes no sense. If you want "/" to go to `lists#new`, just *do* that, with `root to: 'lists#new'`. What does `static_pages/home` have to do with anything?

Comment: @Sontya I don't have that `index.html` file, but with the update you suggested, `/static_pages/home/` does render the right view now. For second question, should the form that will be on this page go into `_form.html.erb` or `home.html.erb`? Thank you!

Comment: @meagar I was under the impression that before you start making the non-static layouts for views in an app, you make all the views under /static_pages/...`? With just   `resources :lists root :to => 'lists#new'` in the routes "/" now renders `_form.html.erb`. Before that it was is the other way around between "/" and `static_pages/home`.

Comment: @sivanes - WHy you need to call partial, in ths lists controller define new method with @list = List.new,  and create a page new.html.erb `<%= form_for @list do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>` , whatever fields you have in your list table

Comment: @Sontya wouldn't using the partial be following the breaking-everything-into-manageable chunks convention?

Comment: @sivanes - yaa thats fine, then you can define your new method as `def new
  respond_to |do|
    format.html
  end
end` and in new.html.erb form render your _form.html.erb as `<%= render :partial => '/form' %>`

Comment: `root 'static_pages#home'` should be last resource of your routes.rb

Comment: @Kuldeep you mean placing it in the end of the routes file? This didn't change anything for me. What's strange is that swapping the two static_pages related lines in the original post to just `root :to => 'lists#new'` leads to `static_pages/home` rendering the `home.html.erb` and "/" rendering `_form.html.erb`. Originally it was the other way around.